# Eigen3 exit code 127 on formatted string output

Tags: c++, eigen3

```
MatrixXd p(10,10);
// set values of p

// for loop prints out all values of p
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  std::cout << p(i/10,i%10) << std::endl;


const IOFormat CleanFmt(4,0,", ","\n","[","]");
std::cout << p.format(CleanFmt);
// fails before running any code with error 1 (cxx = 20)
// fails before running any code with error 127 (cxx = 14/11)
```

Having trouble debugging this, as it is failing outright.  My OS setup is Cygwin in Windows. Perhaps it is failing since windows does not support FIFO-Qs?

Or is something wrong going on here?

Comment: Can you provide a full [mre] (also state which compiler and Eigen version you are using)? Your problem might be elsewhere. `Eigen::IOFormat` should not depend on anything OS-related.

Comment: @chtz will do when I get a chance.  The manual print code is like an infection in the project.